# Cron parser and validation in python

Tags: python, django, cron

I am currently running a django web app in python where I store cron entries entered by the user into a database. I was wondering if there are any python libraries/packages that will validate these entries before I store them into the database. By validate I mean correct syntax as well as the correct range (ex: month cannot be 15). Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Just provide user only the available options in the form of listbox or something.

Comment: I don't think this is a possibility since there are atleast 60*24*31*12*7 unique valid entries the user can enter, and listing all of these in a list box doesn't seem smart. And this is ignoring the use of commas, dashes, and forward slashes in the syntax.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [Croniter](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/croniter/) package seems like it may get what you need. Example from the docs:

```
>>> from croniter import croniter
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> base = datetime(2010, 1, 25, 4, 46)
>>> iter = croniter('*/5 * * * *', base)  # every 5 minites
>>> print iter.get_next(datetime)   # 2010-01-25 04:50:00
>>> print iter.get_next(datetime)   # 2010-01-25 04:55:00
>>> print iter.get_next(datetime)   # 2010-01-25 05:00:00
>>>
>>> iter = croniter('2 4 * * mon,fri', base)  # 04:02 on every Monday and Friday
>>> print iter.get_next(datetime)   # 2010-01-26 04:02:00
>>> print iter.get_next(datetime)   # 2010-01-30 04:02:00
>>> print iter.get_next(datetime)   # 2010-02-02 04:02:00
```

Per the [code](https://github.com/taichino/croniter/blob/master/croniter/croniter.py), it also appears to do validation on the entered format. Likely that you came across this already, but just in case :)

Comment: Hmm I did come across it, but didn't think it did validation as well. I quickly tried it out and it seems to suit my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Since the accepted answer is quite old, the same library has a `croniter.is_valid()` method now. From [docs](https://pypi.org/project/croniter/#usage):

```
>>> croniter.is_valid('0 0 1 * *')  # True
>>> croniter.is_valid('0 wrong_value 1 * *')  # False
```